# Non-Recursive Fundamental Recurrence Formulas

Tags: elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions, project-euler

Is there a non-recursive version of the [fundamental recurrence formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_recurrence_formulas#Fundamental_recurrence_formulas) for continued fractions? I am trying to compute $A_{1000}$, and it is taking me an extremely long time.

By the way, I am expanding $\sqrt2=1+1/(2+\cdots)$.

Comment: Strange -- you seem to be talking about continued fractions; you seem to be using the term "fundamental recurrence formulas" to refer to fundamental recurrence formulas for continued fractions; yet you never mention continued fractions, and you didn't add the [tag:continued-fractions] tag.

Comment: I am sorry... I made the changes you want.

Comment: What exactly do you want? A way to compute a number, given its recurrence formulas?

Comment: @TMM, apparently OP wants an explicit expression for the numerator and denominator of the $n$-th convergent of the CF for $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Note that recurrence relations are not at heart _recursive_ - by the concept of _memoization_ you should be able to compute the $n$th member of a linear recurrence relation like the one for this continued fraction in $O(n)$ operations (on, admittedly, very large numbers - but even that's easy here, since all of those operations can be additions).  If you're doing it 'recursively' - calling FindDenom(n-1) as part of FindDenom(n), for example - then you should be looking at that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is about the [57th problem from Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=57), and feel that it might be more of a question on programming and creating an optimised algorithm.

You can try to set up better recurrences. Let $d_t$ and $n_t$ denote the $t$-th denominator and numerator respectively. Then you'll find the following recurrence relations.
$$
\begin{align*}
d_t&=d_{t-1}+n_{t-1} \\
n_t&=2d_{t-1}+n_{t-1} \\
\Rightarrow n_t&=d_t+d_{t-1}
\end{align*}
$$
You can also find recurrence relations which are exclusive of one another (so the denominator recurrence relation contains no terms dependent upon the numerator and vice versa).
$$
\begin{align*}
d_t&=2d_{t-1}+d_{t-2} \\
n_t&=2n_{t-1}+n_{t-2}
\end{align*}
$$
Given that $d_0=n_0=1$, and $d_1=2$, $n_1=3$, the denominators actually form the sequence of [Pell numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellNumber.html), and so there is a closed form for the denominator that I'm familiar with.
$$
d_{t}=\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^{t+1}-(1-\sqrt{2})^{t+1}}{2\sqrt{2}}
$$
You can also calculate a closed form for the numerator.
$$
n_{t}=\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^{t+1}+(1-\sqrt{2})^{t+1}}{2}
$$